# whisper error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I am trying to use the whisper package for Python from OpenAI to extract the text from an audio file .mp4. I am using the simplest example in their page:

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")

# load audio and pad/trim it to fit 30 seconds
audio = whisper.load_audio("./portuguese.mp4")
audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio)

# make log-Mel spectrogram and move to the same device as the model
mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)

# detect the spoken language
_, probs = model.detect_language(mel)
print(f"Detected language: {max(probs, key=probs.get)}")

# decode the audio
options = whisper.DecodingOptions(fp16 = False)
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)

# print the recognized text
print(result.text)
```

This code returns the following error:

```
  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Downloads/audio_to_text.py:18
    result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py:115 in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/whisper/decoding.py:811 in decode

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py:115 in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/whisper/decoding.py:744 in run
    tokens: List[List[int]] = [t[i].tolist() for i, t in zip(selected, tokens)]

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/whisper/decoding.py:744 in <listcomp>
    tokens: List[List[int]] = [t[i].tolist() for i, t in zip(selected, tokens)]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

This is particularly odd since when I run the command line on a terminal,

```
whisper portuguese.mp4 --language Portuguse
```

it works just fine. How can I solve this error?

Comment: What the version of `whisper`? Also, have you ever install `ffmpeg` for python?

Comment: ```openai-whisper==20230314``` and my ffmpeg version is ```ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)```

Comment: Just checked this; [whisper/decoding.py:744](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/b91c907694f96a3fb9da03d4bbdc83fbcd3a40a4/whisper/decoding.py#L744). This could be related to the `fp16=False` parameter you have provided. That's the only difference between your Python code and the CLI command. Also, there's no `fp16=False` in the examples section of the repo. I'd start there.

Comment: If I don't use this parameter, I get the error: ```"slow_conv2d_cpu" not implemented for 'Half'``` as can be seen in https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/92.

Comment: Oh okay, so you are not using a GPU. This might be a long shot but: can you try a super short audio file? According to [this](https://github.com/openai/whisper/pull/1317) pull request, it might throw an index error if it encounters an empty segment. Trim the audio to just the audible part if necessary.